# Ajax with spring mvc + hibernate

Tags: ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

If I have list of items to show that I get from database.
Besides each item there is a button to remove it.
Clicking on the button should remove relation with user and undisplay it.

Im using Spring MVC + hibernate. Is it possible to do it with AJAX?

I dont understand how to use ajax with spring and mvc. How do I get the list of items, remove an item from it and then send back to jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Thats too broad question to answer in depth. Seems you miss some knowledge how spring mvc works itself.

You need to fetch List of rows using hibernate, then add it to mvc model in your controller then you will be able to list them using jsp.

If you have it, then start reading about contollers which read/write JSON ( @RequestBody/@ResponseBody ).